# \end{align} error due to equation

Tags: equations, subequations

Currently I have a a set of equations with nested text in between them using intertext, however I have a problem with the last equation refusing to  output (eq:4.3)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
hello123
\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{align}
\left ( \frac{\partial \rho }{\partial t}+u_{i}\frac{\partial \rho }{\partial x_{j}}\right )+\rho \frac{\partial u_{i} }{\partial x_{i}}&=0 \label{eq:1.1}\\
\rho\left(\frac{\partial u_{i}}{\partial t}+u_{i}\frac{\partial u_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}\right)+\frac{\partial P}{\partial x_{j}}&=\mu\left(\frac{\partial^2 u_{i}}{\partial x_{j}^2}\right)+\rho g \label{eq:1.2}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

hello123
\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{align}
u\left(\overrightarrow{r}\right)=\lim_{T \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1}{T}\int_{t}^{t+T} u(\overrightarrow{r},t)dt\right)\label{eq:2.1}
\intertext{hello123}
\left(\overrightarrow{r},t\right)=\lim_{V \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1}{V}\iiint u(\overrightarrow{r},t)dt\right)\label{eq:2.2}
\intertext{hello123}
u\left(\overrightarrow{r},t\right)=\lim_{V \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^Mu_n\left(\overrightarrow{r},t\right)\label{eq:2.3}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
hello123
\par
hello123
\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{align}
u&=\overline{u}+u' \label{eq:3.1}\\
P&=\overline{P}+P' \label{eq:3.2}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
hello123
\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{align}
\rho\left(\frac{\partial\left(\overline{ u_{i}}+u_i'\right)}{\partial t}+\left(\overline u_{i}+u_i'\right)\frac{\partial \left(\overline{ u_{i}}+u_i'\right)}{\partial x_{j}}\right)+\frac{\partial \left(\overline P+P'\right)}{\partial x_{j}}&=\mu\left(\frac{\partial^2 \left(\overline u_{i}+u_{i}'\right)}{\partial x_{j}^2}\right)+\rho g \label{eq:4.1}
\intertext{hello123}
\rho\left(\frac{\partial\left(\overline{ u_{i}}\right)}{\partial t}+\overline u_{i}\frac{\partial \left(\overline{ u_{i}}\right)}{\partial x_{j}}\right)+\frac{\partial \left(\overline P\right)}{\partial x_{j}}&=\mu\left(\frac{\partial^2 \left(\overline u_{i}\right)}{\partial x_{j}^2}\right)+\rho g \label{eq:4.2}
\intertext{hello123}
\rho\left(\frac{\partial\langle u_{i}\rangle}{\partial t}+\left(\langle u_{i}\rangle\langle u_{j}\rangle\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}+\langle u_{i}'u_{j}'\rangle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\right )+\frac{\partial \langle P\rangle}{\partial x_{j}}=\mu\triangledown^2\langle u_{i}\rangle-\frac{\partial \langle\tau\rangle}{\partial x_{j}}\label{eq4.3}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

I recieve the following error message for line 45

```
\end{align}
```

[image]

The code works perfectly without eq:4.3, so I am assuming it has to do with the length of the equation not being able to align properly?

Comment: apart from the undefined command you are using align without specifying any alignment points (`&`) which is always wrong):`amsmath` has `gather` and `multline` environments for non aligned math displays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get say that the macro (control sequence) `\triangledown` is undefined. It is impossible to see from your screenshot, but if you open the `.log` file, you'll see that it says

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...}{\partial x_{j}}=\mu \triangledown 
                                                  ^2\langle u_{i}\rangle -\f...
l.51 \end{align}

?
```

The last macro before the linebreak is the one that is undefined/unknown, in this case `\triangledown`.

Add

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

to fix it.

Comment: Also, the last equation has no ampersand, and this causes problems with alignment.

Comment: @IanThompson Thanks, I didn't really look at the output, just checked that it worked with `amssymb`.

Comment: Ah thank you so much, I thought I already had amssymb in my preamble. Looks like i was wrong